# How to use OleDbCommand to insert into different tables?

Tags: c#, oledbcommand

How do I properly use an `OleDbCommand` to insert into two different tables? Here is what I have tried so far:

```
GradeConn.Open();
oledDbCmd.Connection = GradeConn;
oledDbCmd.CommandText = "insert into StudentInfo (IdNumber, LastName,FirstName,MiddleName,YearSection,MidtermGrade) values ('" +
    txbIdNumber.Text + "','" +
    txbLastName.Text + "','" +
    txbFirstName.Text + "','" +
    txbMiddleName.Text + "','" +
    txbYearSection.Text + "','" +
    dmg + "')"; "insert into MidTerm  (IdNumber,StudentName, QuizzesSeatworks,ClassParticipation,Attendance,Assignments, LaboratoryExercises, CaseStudy,Behavior,ClassStanding,MidtermExam,MidtermGrade )   values('" +
    txbIdNumber.Text + "', '" +
    txbStudentName.Text + "','" +
    mquiz + "','" +
    mcp + "','" +
    matt + "','" +
    mass + "','" +
    mlab + "','" +
    mcstu + "','" +
    mbeh + "','" +
    mstanding + "','" +
    mte + "','" +
    dmg + "')";

int temp = oledDbCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
if (temp > 0)
{
    txbIdNumber.Text = null;
    txbLastName = null;
    txbFirstName.Text = null;
    txbMiddleName.Text = null;
    txbYearSection.Text = null;
    txbStudentName.Text = null;
    MessageBox.Show("Records Successfully Added");
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Records Fail to Added");
}
```

Comment: I edited the title so that people can understand the problem at a glance, and removed the unnecessary salutation. I've also formatted the code, especially the SQL strings, to be more readable. Although it may be apparent to knowledgable people why the code is not working, it's always helpful to include what your expected outcome is, and the actual result you're seeing.

Comment: What is the error you have received?

Comment: @ento  Sir the error is "Characters found after end of SQL statement

Comment: @InvernoMuto operator '+' cannot be applied to operand to type 'string'

Comment: @SelvaTS Sir the error is "Characters found after end of SQL statement

Answer (score 1):

Change to this and try. You are missing ; (semicolon in the queries)

```
oledDbCmd.CommandText = "insert into StudentInfo (IdNumber, LastName,FirstName,MiddleName,YearSection,MidtermGrade) values ('" +
    txbIdNumber.Text + "','" +
    txbLastName.Text + "','" +
    txbFirstName.Text + "','" +
    txbMiddleName.Text + "','" +
    txbYearSection.Text + "','" +
    dmg + "'); INSERT into MidTerm  (IdNumber,StudentName, QuizzesSeatworks,ClassParticipation,Attendance,Assignments, LaboratoryExercises, CaseStudy,Behavior,ClassStanding,MidtermExam,MidtermGrade )   values('" +
    txbIdNumber.Text + "', '" +
    txbStudentName.Text + "','" +
    mquiz + "','" +
    mcp + "','" +
    matt + "','" +
    mass + "','" +
    mlab + "','" +
    mcstu + "','" +
    mbeh + "','" +
    mstanding + "','" +
    mte + "','" +
    dmg + "')";
```